# Including the content of HTML page as String in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

here is my problem. I need to include the content of some HTML page(template) in some string in jsp file, so I could iterate threw it, parse it, and use just thing what i need. How could accomplish this, I was trying to find solution online but I couldn't. Does anyone know what the solution might be?

Thanks,

Luka

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to read an HTML page from the web and parse it to grab certain pieces of data, then the following code might be helpful to you (quick and dirty code I used in a previous project)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy;

public List<String> getTopics() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(TOPIC_URL);
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        java.io.InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream();
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setDocType("HTML 4.01 Transitional");
        tidy.setQuiet(true);
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(is, null);

        XPathFactory  factory=XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath=factory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression  xPathExpression= xPath.compile("//td[@class='topics']//table[@class='topic']/tr/td/a/text()");
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        logger.debug("Found " + nodes.getLength() + " nodes");

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<nodes.getLength();i++){
            result.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        }
        logger.debug("Topics: " + result);
        return result;
    } catch(MalformedURLException ex) {
        logger.info(ex.getClass() + ":" + ex.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } catch(XPathExpressionException ex) {
        logger.info(ex.getClass() + ":" + ex.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        logger.info(ex.getClass() + ":" + ex.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Obviously, it's worth noting:

- Its bad to convert everything to a RuntimeException
- Your XPath expressions will be different than mine
- Tidy is used to clean up the HTML and parse it like XML
- If you want to read from a file on the file system, then you'd do that rather than the URL stuff
- This code should probably be broken up into multiple methods (get the html, parse the html, get the information from the Document... something like that)

Comment: Thanks but I need it from local file

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to understand you question but you can include a template using the include tag

```
<jsp:include page="template.html">
```

This will read the html-file when the JSP page is compiled and make it part of the page.

Comment: I know what he intends to do: He might want read in a html file as string and then do some string manipulation and then out.print the manipulated results.

Answer (score 0):

If file which you try to read is a local file, then I suggest to try [Files.toString()](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) from [Google Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
File file = new File("test.txt");
String res = Files.toString(file, charset);
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe that would do it, i'll try, i just focused on JSP and include directive, meanwhile forgetting basics :)

Comment: I did the job with this:

    <%
            String file = application.getRealPath("/") + "test.txt";
            File fileObject = new File(file);

            char data[] = new char[(int) fileObject.length()];
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);

            int charsread = filereader.read(data);
            out.println(new String(data, 0 , charsread));

            filereader.close();
        %>

and it worked just great, but thank you guys anyway ;)